# How to get a Table Object by table's name by sqlalchemy and query in it？

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, sqlalchemy, orm

I want to query some information from a pointed table in a database(I don't like native SQL sentences), and this is my code:

```
import sqlalchemy as sqa

sl_database_link = 'mssql+pymsql://……'
sl_engine = sqa.create_engine(sl_database_link)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=sl_engine))
insp_sl = inspect(sl_engine)
tables = insp_sl.get_table_names()
session.query('the table which I want to query')
```

But after I getting a table name, I don't know how to query the table by its name correctly, can someone tell me?

I have find some posts on StackOverflow, but every result can't solve my problem.

Comment: Normally you should know which table to query at compile time and not at run time. Sounds like your DB design is terribly wrong.

Comment: This database comes from another organization so I don't know what table it has before I read it by inspect().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to query a single table you get the object via the [Table](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) class.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
...
tbl = sa.Table(name_of_table, sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)

with engine.connect() as conn:
    rows = conn.execute(sa.select(tbl))
```

If you want more than one table you can use [metadata.reflect](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.reflect):

```py
metadata = sa.MetaData()
# Omit "only" to reflect all tables
metadata.reflect(engine, only=[name_of_table1, name_of_table2, ...])
my_table = metadata.tables[name_of_table]
```

See the docs for [Reflecting Database Objects](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/reflection.html) and, if you prefer to work with ORM models, the [Automap](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/automap.html#module-sqlalchemy.ext.automap) extension.

Comment: I have seen this document before asking the problem, however when I run this code:```table_obj = Table(st_table, md)
        session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=sl_engine))
        result = session.query(table_obj).all()```, it crashed with"sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Query contains no columns with which to SELECT from".

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [mre]. From the looks of your code you don't have `autoload_with=engine` in your table definition, so you are just defining an empty table.

Comment: Oh I know, I wrote this code `Table(name='str_name', metadata=MetaData(), autoload_with=sl_engine)` at first, however it's a mistake.```metadata.reflect(engine, only=[name_of_table1, name_of_table2, ...])
my_table = metadata.tables[name_of_table]         table_obj = Table(st_table, md, autoload_with=engine)``` is correct.